# Lost connection to iPad with the memory warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

We have used `SWReavelViewController` for menu, `UIContainerView` to load same `viewController` with MKMapView at multiple screen, MkMapView even in some tableview cell also, multiple annotation on map.

When we use app continuously for 4 to 5 minute due to some memory warning it cause crash.

We can't found any kind of root cause of this crash.

We did try to find root cause using `[![Instruments][1]][1]` but still no luck.

Following is the instrumentation log image.

[image]

Please, can anybody have suggest to solve this issue.

Any suggestion will appreciable.

Comment: capture the phone logs and share.

Comment: Which part of Instruments did you use? Allocation? Memory Leaks? Try to check before hand if there is a leak, then, check what could be deallocated/released when not needed.

Comment: Zombies -> call tree

Comment: Are you using any high resolution images? That might cause this problem because I had faced this earlier.

Comment: @Santosh. Thank's for you replay. But i am not using any high resolution image in my app.

Comment: For rough estimation of how much memory is currently used, you can also  use Xcodes built-in memory usage (View->Navigators->Show Debug Navigator (CMD+6). Had a similar issue that the app crashed and the debugger immediately detached. I think you do allocate somewhere objects, which are not freed anymore. Maybe malloc_history helps you out here? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001882-CJBJFIDD